# Weapon smith Ornifex died in Shaded Ruins and there is no tombstone

Tags: dark-souls-2

I got swamped by Basiliks in the shaded ruins whilst freeing Ornifex and she got petrified to death :( She did mention that she would re-locate to Brightstone Cove Tseldora before she died, however when i return to either locations there is no tombstone to be found.
Is this just bad luck, or is there some other way of getting that tombstone to appear (excluding restarting from scratch or NG+)

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've tested killing several important NPCs such as merchants and I have seen that they "come back" as tombstones after a few "real world" hours. The same applies to Ornifex, her tombstone will appear in her prison cell when killed. I believe the amount of souls you need to trade with her is 11,000 souls.

In any case, if the tombstone is not there after a few hours or even restarting the console and the game, I don't think you'll have any other option than to start NG+. Alternatively, you could use a Bonfire Ascetic at the nearest Bonfire to force that area alone into NG+; it'll make everything, including any bosses, respawn as NG+ level, but will also respawn all NPCs and most lootables.

Comment: +1 Thx for the reply, Ornifex died ages ago in the Shaded Ruins but only found the lower cove bonfire and Ornifex's house much later on. So will give it another go tonight. I have killed other NPC's before and their tombstones spawned pretty quickly. But still, everything is possible in DS2! Bit torn about the bonfire ascetic as imo its not the best area to grind souls, (Iron Keep 2nd Bonfire springs to mind) which imo is mostly the point of them.

Comment: But it's not true for everybody, is it? In my first runthrough I killed the starting merchant in Majula and even after 40+ hours of gameplay there was never any kind of tombstone?!

Comment: @Sorcy it's supposed to be true, I've heard it doesn't happen for a lot of players, but it did happen for me. The information out there says it should happen but as Timmah said, anything is possible in DS2.

Comment: Well after playing quite some time now i returned back to the room with the candle in Brightstone Cove Tseldora and no grave to be found :( Looks like it might be NG+ only. Once i have a few more bonfire ascetics i'll venture that path... Keep you all posted!

Comment: Actually Timmah I believe we've has a misunderstanding, it's not in the room with the candle but rather the cell in which you found Ornifex in the Forest of Fallen Giants for the first time.

Comment: @Ozmah aren't you referring to [Merchant Hag Melentia](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Forest+of+Fallen+Giants)?  I'll have another look in the shaded ruins later but i do think it's tickets and NG+ is the only way...

Comment: No, I'm referring to the bird-like weapon smith. The one you find trapped in a prison cell under a wooden floor that collapses, surrounded by Basilisks.

Comment: OK but that is in the Shaded Ruins not the Forrest of Fallen Giants :)

Comment: Ppffff sorry about that, as you could see by my second answer I was half asleep u_u

Comment: Ok i can confirm now that Ornifex is well and truly gone. (ie. no tombstone in Shaded Ruins or Brightstone Cove Tseldora after coming back on several occasions). Better luck next time i guess, in NG+.